# How to search for martial matches when mysql query contains a placeholder in python?

Tags: python, replace, variable-expansion

Query 1:

`"SELECT name FROM mytable WHERE name LIKE '%e%'";`

This query will look for all names that contain the letter ‘e’.

Query 2:

`"SELECT name FROM mytable WHERE name LIKE '%s'" % search_name;`

This query will look for all names that contain match search_name exactly.

What I want to know is if there is a way to query for a partial match like in query 1 while using the placeholder in query 2?

I have tried something like:

`"SELECT name FROM mytable WHERE name LIKE %'%s'%" % search_name;` <- didn’t work;
`"SELECT name FROM mytable WHERE name LIKE '%%s%'" % search_name;` <- also didn’t work;

Comment: I don't think this has got anything to do with MySQL or sql. You must be using some kind of a programming language that can expand the `%s` placeholder. This is a question for that programming language, not for any of the tags you used for this question. The tags added by Vadim are completely irrelevant as well.

Comment: Your right sorry, I am running the sql queries in python, which is where the placeholder comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use a different way of formatting the string inside your query string like

```
SELECT name FROM mytable WHERE name LIKE '%" + search_name + "%'"
```

or f-Strings.

Or you could add more % and escape it with a slash so it gets put into the string normally.

```
\%%s\%
```